# How to use Hangfire when using MEF to load plugins?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, mef, hangfire

I'm using MEF in my WebApi project to load plugins located in a folder other than the bin folder. I do the following:

```
var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins"));

var container = new CompositionContainer(directoryCatalog);
container.ComposeParts();

IList<IPlugin> plugins = container.GetExportedValues<IPlugin>().ToList();
```

Then I'm setting up a plugin by doing:

```
plugins[0].Startup(logService, unitOfWork);
```

Note: I'm not using `[ImportingConstructor]` to pass the above dependencies because I'm using existing instances already instantiated in the controller.

Then I schedule the job as follows:

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => plugins[0].Start(), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
```

However, I get the following exception when Hangfire tries to start the job:

> Could not load file or assembly 'App.Plugins.FirstPlugin, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Is it even possible to use MEF and Hangfire together in this kind of scenario? If yes, what is the correct procedure?

**NOTE:**
If the plugin DLL's are located in the same bin folder as the main app, Hangfire works fine. But this defeats the purpose to have a separate plugins folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to guide hangfire (or rather - .NET itself) for the location of this assembly by subscribing to `AppDomain.AssemblyResolve` event (somewhere before starting hangfire server):

```
var pluginPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "plugins");
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
    var asmName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    var plugin = Path.Combine(pluginPath, asmName.Name + ".dll");
    if (File.Exists(plugin))
        return Assembly.LoadFrom(plugin);
    return null;
};
```

Since your plugins are actually already loaded into current app domain (by MEF), the following should also work (and I think might be better than above):

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => {
    var asmName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
    var existing = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FullName == asmName.FullName);
    if (existing != null) {
        return existing;
    }
    return null;
};
```

That's necessary because hangfire, to deserialize instance of your plugin from state in database, uses `Type.GetType` providing assembly qualified name, and because of certain complications which (I think) are not relevant for this question - `Type.GetType` will not find your plugin assembly, even though it is already loaded by MEF into current app domain, so you have to help it a bit.

Comment: I placed the above code within `Application_Start` in `Global.asax`. Still have the same problem.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono try first code block (that one which uses `pluginPath`) and put it as first statement in `Application_Start`.

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono I've also fixed second code block (which does not use pluginPath), it should also work now in `Application_Start`.

Answer (score 1):

On the [Hangfire Extensions](https://www.hangfire.io/extensions.html) page, there's a notion of the NuGet package **Hangfire.MEF**.

It leads to [Hangfire.MEF - Hangfire background job activator based on MEF IoC Container](https://github.com/Excommunicated/Hangfire.MEF). I think it might help you with your problem.

Comment: From what I can understand, this extension is used to inject dependencies through the constructor of a MEF part.